# How will the Intrinsic matrix changes if the dimension of the 3d grid changes?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, photogrammetry

I have calibrated pictures around an object with unknown dimensions and points.
The problem is that the extrinsics calibration is not fairly accurate as I don't exactly know the distance between the camera and the object that it turns around.
I can find the known length of this object (thus the distance between two 3D points could be 25 thanks to triangulation and 30 in real life).
How can I correct the intrinsic parameters of my camera calibration to minimize the geometric error?

I have some difficulties to know what terms I have to look for (to get results on Google that would help me).
I found some minimization methods that requires a match between image points and corresponding 3d points (that I don't have) but this doesn't help me much.

Does just multiplying the distance with a computed scale factor works for all distances?

EDIT : There is a rigidity constrains. Only one camera takes all the pictures. So only one intrinsic matrix is needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use camera in the singular, I assume this is not a stereo setup. If your camera is already well calibrated, i.e., you accurately know its intrinsic parameters, your problem is not one of calibration, but of scale:

- If you know the size of your 3D object, you can accurately retrieve the motion of the camera around it - as accurately as you can match corresponding points on the object across images.
- If you do not know its size, you can accurately reconstruct the camera rotations, but the translations only up to an unknown global scale

Comment: Thank you very much.
Your assumption was right, thus I edited the question.
If I understand right, considering every image was calibrated without knowing the size of the object, I just have to find the global scale back.
For example, if on my model, the object is 10cm long and it is 12cm long in real life.
All I have to do is to factor each distance with a ratio of 1.2?

Comment: Yes, more or less. You could solve for the motion assuming, for example, that your object is enclosed in a box of height 1. Once you have the solution, multiplying the motion for the actual height yields the real motion.